# Specify filename in python script to open Excel workbook

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

this is a really dumb question, but Im trying to learn python and I got stuck on example with reading Excel files using xlrd. 
I found this script online but I cant figure out where am I supposed to fill my filename to get it open.

```
from future import print_function
from os.path import join, dirname, abspath, isfile
from collections import Counter
import xlrd
from xlrd.sheet import ctype_text
```

def get_excel_sheet_object(fname, idx=0):
    if not isfile(fname):
        print ('File doesn't exist: ', fname)
            # Open the workbook and 1st sheet
    xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(fname)
    xl_sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    print (40 * '-' + 'nRetrieved worksheet: %s' % xl_sheet.name)

`return xl_sheetsdf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enter the filename :

- When you call the function

  get_excel_sheet_object("myfile.xlsx")

  ```
         OR
  ```

  fname = "myfile.xlsx"

  get_excel_sheet_object(fname)
- Raw in your program :

  ```
  def get_excel_sheet_object(idx=0):

        fname = "myfile.xlsx"

        if not isfile(fname):
           print ("File doesn't exist: ", fname)
        # Open the workbook and 1st sheet
        xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(fname)
        xl_sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
        print (40 * '-' + 'nRetrieved worksheet: %s' % xl_sheet.name)

        return xl_sheet
  ```

Comment: Thanks but still doesnt work. I have the excel file in the same folder, do I need to specify the full path nevertheles?

Comment: well, it said the syntax is wrong. I removed the ' from "don't" and its working now, thanks!

Comment: great, so could you accept the answer if it helps you ?

Answer (score 0):

```
from future import print_function
from os.path import join, dirname, abspath, isfile
from collections import Counter
import xlrd
from xlrd.sheet import ctype_text   


def get_excel_sheet_object(fname, idx=0):
    if not isfile(fname):
        print ('File doesn't exist: ', fname)
            # Open the workbook and 1st sheet
    xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(fname)
    xl_sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    print (40 * '-' + 'nRetrieved worksheet: %s' % xl_sheet.name)

    return xl_sheet

xl_sheet_obj = get_excel_sheet_object('FILE_NAME_HERE')
```

Do anything you want with `xl_sheet_obj` after that this object is the excel sheet object.